# Update a session array with jquery / ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a somewhat theoretical question this time:

The situation (on a PHP website):

1. members on a website can add cd's to their 'favorite list'
2. onClick of the like-button, jQuery/ajax ads the cd to the favorite
   list
3. another file renews the session array [favCDS]
4. goal: the user always has his latest clicks updated real time,
   because live-data is generated from stored arrays)

The question:

Would it be possible to update a SESSION array of personal member values with a function, through a file running on the background, called by and updated through jQuery/ajax?

I imagine it would be updating it all in one file, but I wonder if you guys have any thoughts/ideas on this.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP session persists even after scripts are finished running, so you don't need a PHP file running in the background on the server.

Example PHP file (called by the ajax function, assuming the ajax function submits a POST request with the CD's id):

**update-favorite.php**

```
$_SESSION['favCDS'][] = $_POST['cd-id'];
```

That way, when the user navigates to a new page, that page can preserve the favorite CDs by accessing this session array and generating HTML accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Jordan!

But does this actually add the $_POST['cd-id'] to the $_SESSION['favCDS'][] then?

Comment: It adds $_POST['cd-id'] to $_SESSION['favCDs'] by means of the `array[] = new item` operator.

Comment: Thank you so much! You just made things much easier to build and make essential updates easy now. Again: thanks!